# Pass parameters for generic NSFetchRequest method

Tags: core-data, parameters, nsfetchrequest

I need to create a common method for many of the views in my project to export data as .csv. For that purpose, I need to pass an "entity" parameter, in order to reuse this function for all of them.

The example code for "Alumno" entity is as follows:

```
func exportData(???) {
    
    let container: NSPersistentContainer? = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer
   
    //*
    var exportData: [Alumno] = []
    let exportRequest: NSFetchRequest<Alumno> = Alumno.fetchRequest()
    //*
    
    let context = container?.viewContext
    
    do {
        exportData = try context!.fetch(exportRequest)
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
    ...
```

Now, how can I pass an "entity" parameter in the method definition (marked with ???), and what should be "exportData" array and "exportRequest" definition (marked with *), in order to reuse this method to be called from other views to export its data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to work for any of your entities, then it doesn't need to know which entity it's working with. It can use `NSManagedObject`, and ignore the subclasses.

This would be something like

```
func exportData(class name: String) -> Void {
    // ...

    var exportData: [NSManagedObject] = []
    let exportRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: name)

    // ...
}
```

The name is all you need for the fetch request. You'll get back a collection of managed objects.

Comment: OK, that's the idea, thanks! But, doing this way I get another error. Later in my code I need to use this objects in a loop to get the .csv values: `for data in exportData`. And `data.csv()` or `data.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)` both throw errors: Value of type 'NSManagedObject' has no member 'csv', and Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'utf8', respectively

Comment: I don't know why the first works (with a concrete subclass) an the second doesn't (with the superclass NSManagedObject) -> (https://dropover.cloud/0e9f2c)

Comment: It's because `csv()` is not part of `NSManagedObject`. It's somewhere in your app. If you extend `NSManagedObject` to include that function then it should work. If you can't do that then you need to edit your question to include more details about your data model.

Comment: Thank you Tom. That's correct! Although there is then another question now. Going on with it on next comment.

Answer (score 0):

Going on with Tom suggestions, he is right: I have defined three csv() methods to get csv strings for each of my entities. For example, "alumno" one:

```
extension Alumno {

func csv() -> String {
    let coalescedNombre = nombre ?? ""
    let coalescedEspecialidad = especialidadRelacionada?.nombre ?? ""
    let coalescedCurso = cursoRelacionado?.nivel ?? ""
    let coalescedTutor = tutorRelacionado?.nombre ?? ""
    let coalescedMovil = movil ?? ""
    let coalescedCorreo = correo ?? ""
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "d MMM y, E HH:mm"
    let coalescedNacimiento = formatter.string(from: nacimiento!)
    return "\(coalescedNombre), \(coalescedEspecialidad), \(coalescedCurso), \(coalescedTutor), \(coalescedMovil), \(coalescedCorreo), \(coalescedNacimiento)\r\n"
}
```

}

But now the problem is: how can I match this coalesced values to populate csv file for its correspondent entity? I mean: I can write en equivalent method for all of them, but, how can I define its values? This doesn't work:

```
extension NSManagedObject {

func csv() -> String {

    var entity = NSManagedObject.entity
    
    if entity == Alumno {
        let coalescedNombre = nombre ?? ""
        let coalescedEspecialidad = especialidadRelacionada?.nombre ?? ""
        let coalescedCurso = cursoRelacionado?.nivel ?? ""
        let coalescedTutor = tutorRelacionado?.nombre ?? ""
        let coalescedMovil = movil ?? ""
        let coalescedCorreo = correo ?? ""
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "d MMM y, E HH:mm"
        let coalescedNacimiento = formatter.string(from: nacimiento!)
        return "\(coalescedNombre), \(coalescedEspecialidad), \(coalescedCurso), \(coalescedTutor), \(coalescedMovil), \(coalescedCorreo), \(coalescedNacimiento)\r\n"

    }

   if entity == ... 

}
```

}